# PlatformNotSupportedException when executing a general LINQ query

Tags: c#, .net, linq, exception, entity-framework-4.1

I get a weird exception on a XP machine when I run a LINQ query.

```
{"The specified cryptographic algorithm is not supported on this platform."}

at System.Security.Cryptography.CapiNative.AcquireCsp(String keyContainer, String providerName, ProviderType providerType, CryptAcquireContextFlags flags, Boolean throwPlatformException)
```

There is no inner exception and the stacktrace is above.

I would expect that kind of exception when cryptography providers are in play etc., but with LINQ, I have no idea. I have to admit I am new to LINQ.

**Here's the slightly simplified LINQ Query in EF 4.1:**

```
using (var c = new MyContext())
{
    var v = (from item in c.Items where (item.ID==someid) select item).FirstOrDefault();
    return v;
}
```

Any insight?

**EDIT:
As already noted in the comments section below, I am using .NET 4.0 with EF 4.1, the connection string is a plain ol' app.config string with no crpto settings or other connection string options applied.**

Comment: I guess the `MyContext`, or items in that context are trying to use cryptography in some way, causing the exception when the items are enumerated.

Comment: Are you using LINQ-to-SQL or Entity Framework? You might want to update your tags accordingly. Also, a small unrelated suggestion - you can replace the two lines inside the `using` block with `retrun c.Items.FirstOrDefault();`.

Comment: Assumption, this is .NET 4.0 because entity-framework-4.1 depends on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly suspect it's the security being used trying to talk to the database - check your connection string and any options you have with respect to encrypting the connection string itself.

Comment: The conn string is a plain old sql server string with WinAuth. No encryption is used.  Data Source=.\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=MyDB;Persist Security Info=True;Integrated Security=True

Comment: this is in the app.config file. I only get this exception when I tell VS to break on all CLR exceptions.

Comment: @John: Ah - in that case it may well be that it's trying to use one level of encryption, and will fall back to a lesser level of encryption otherwise.

Comment: So what do you suspect this means?

Comment: @John: That it's not a problem. Basically you're seeing an exception which would be caught slightly higher up.